# Efficient way to create jQuery widgets for a dashboard

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing a dashboard for users to view statistics and other info that's retrieved from a MySQL database. There are around 10 widgets on one page and I'm concerned about speed and efficiency. The widgets are basic jQuery posts and JSON responses... See code below. Is this approach OK? Or is there are better way? Also I would like to import later these widgets to other pages on the site. How can this be done? The simple solution would be to include the JavaScript file and its container. But I would like to limit code as much as possible.

JavaScript FILE

```
function getLatest(mode) {ç
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./demo2/contents/updates/getLatest.php",
data: {mode:mode},
cache: false,
dataType: "json",
success: function(response){

NotifyPage('Retrieved '+response['count']+' records','success'); 
BlockPortlet('#kt_widget6_tab1_content','Loading..');
HidePortlet(1000,'#kt_widget6_tab1_content');

$("#latestContainer").html(response['data']);

}

});

}
```

PHP

```
$count = 0;
$result = db_query($query);
while($row = db_fetch_array($result))
{

$fieldArray["title"]        = "title 22";
$fieldArray["shortDesc"]    = "Desc";
$fieldArray["icon"]         = "item-icon";
$fieldArray["timeAgo"]      = "2 hrs ago";

$saveData .= requireToVarArray('templates/itemsLatest.php',$fieldArray);

$count++; 
}

$returnArray["data"]    = $saveData;
$returnArray["count"]   = $count;

echo json_encode($returnArray);

exit;
```

PHP file 2

```
<a href="#" class="kt-notification__item">

 <div class="kt-notification__item-icon">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" class="kt-svg-icon kt-svg-icon--brand">
 <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
 <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"/>
 <path d="M5,3 L6,3 C6.55228475,3 7,3.44771525 7,4 L7,20 C7,20.5522847 6.55228475,21 6,21 L5,21 C4.44771525,21 4,20.5522847 4,20 L4,4 C4,3.44771525 4.44771525,3 5,3 Z M10,3 L11,3 C11.5522847,3 12,3.44771525 12,4 L12,20 C12,20.5522847 11.5522847,21 11,21 L10,21 C9.44771525,21 9,20.5522847 9,20 L9,4 C9,3.44771525 9.44771525,3 10,3 Z" fill="#000000"/>
 <rect fill="#000000" opacity="0.3" transform="translate(17.825568, 11.945519) rotate(-19.000000) translate(-17.825568, -11.945519) " x="16.3255682" y="2.94551858" width="3" height="18" rx="1"/>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>

 <div class="kt-notification__item-details">
 <div class="kt-notification__item-title">
 <?=$fieldArray["title"]?>
 </div>
 <div class="kt-notification__item-time">
  <?=$fieldArray["timeAgo"]?>
 </div>
 </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: This approach is ok. I personally like to return the data as JSON, and parse the HTML inside the browser using a framework like angular, backbone or vue, which can save a lot of time. You are basically doing this server side in php which is also ok, but maybe less flexible... Maybe you want the other widget you wish to implement later just a little different for example.

Comment: Upon reading your question again, what are you actually asking?

Comment: thanks Vincent. Could you explain this "parse the HTML inside the browser using a framework like angular"

Comment: my second question is how can I import these widgets in other pages with as little code as possible..

Comment: With using angular or another framework I mean only return the data in JSON format from the PHP side, and worry about the HTML in the browser. This way when you need the widget on another page just call the javascript that generates the widget. Like you have now.

Comment: The amount of code you will have to code be more or less the same.

Comment: thanks makes sense.